# How many actors will reprise their roles in Star Trek: Picard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

The upcoming *Star Trek: Picard* web/ TV series will happen 20 years after the events of *Star Trek: Nemesis*. Nemesis was released in 2002 which is exactly 18 years ago. So, age of the actors wouldn't matter much if they want to cast them in *Star Trek: Picard*.

I know that Patrick Stewart is coming back as Picard.

[image]

I am interested to know who else is coming back.

Comment: Only [a handful of cast members](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt8806524/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_tt_cl_sc) have been reveiled so far, and Picard is the only returning member so far

Comment: Where's this capture from?   I am so glad to see that uniform to his right!

Comment: @ThePopMachine This image is a photo of a video clip shown at CBS' Upfronts presentation. Upfronts are hosted by TV networks like CBS to show off the next season's slate of shows primarily to advertisers, but sometimes to press as well.

Comment: CBS will likely keep any cameos a secret until shortly before the show or respective episode airs.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: the uniform is to *his* left, and to *our* right.

Comment: See this question again, I just don't see how this isn't massively afoul of the Future Works policy.   The answer is 
likely to keep changing and also is immediately available when the works are released.

Comment: Rhetorically:  Could I ask which languages will apear on the show?   What planets he will visit?  How many outfits he will wear?   At what temperature does he order his tea?

Comment: @ThePopMachine The last one can be answered now! He doesn't specify, he orders it decaf. :)